# Array formula is not working with the combination of Vlookup and Indirect-Match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to generate an arrayformula for the whole column but it does not work, when I use the same formula cell by cell, it generates correct value. Here is the formula for `F1` cell:

```
=if(Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(E1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=E1,"",Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(E1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))
```

I am trying to convert it into ArrayFormula like this and put it in `F1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(Iferror(vlookup($D:$D, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH($E:$E,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=$E:$E,"",Iferror(vlookup($D:$D, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH($E:$E,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")))
```

But this does not work and returns empty column, here is the sheet if you want to test it, you can find formula in column F:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13XLZvvdzK_mqr4Ous50cIEfernw2XrPJWvVgt1hFxtk/edit?usp=sharing

Please share your knowledge how to go about it as I am trying to learn formulas starting from basic level? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when working with more than one condition, you can usually use FILTER for it. In this case, I used MAP to refer to both columns D and E, and used FILTER to narrow to the matches in A column, and then to those values that were further than the row of the MATCH of E value. Then, with INDEX I chose the first value of that resulting range.

```
=MAP(D:D,E:E,LAMBDA(d,e,IFERROR(IF(d="","",INDEX(FILTER(B:B,A:A=d,ROW(B:B)>MATCH(e,B:B,0)),1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, certainly it did produce the correct results in whole column, however I was hoping to apply `ARRAYFORMULA` on `=if(Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(E1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=E1,"",Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(E1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))`, I believe it is not gonna work on this,

Comment: Yes, you actually can do it. But ARRAYFORMULA is not the only way of creating array formulas. In fact, it's the most "primitive" one since it has to interpret which of the values is steady and which has to drag. MAP, BYROW, BYCOL, etc, are other options. You can actually convert your exact formula with MAP too: `=MAP(D1:D,E1:E,LAMBDA(dx,ex,if(Iferror(vlookup(dx, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(ex,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=ex,"",Iferror(vlookup(dx, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(ex,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))))`

Comment: Thank you, I have more complex formulas moving forward in the columns (G,H,I,..) like this:

`=if(or(Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=E1,Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=F1,Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=G1)
,"",Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))`

Can we use the same approach?

Comment: If you need to expand in both ways, I suggest you look into MAKEARRAY. With the use of INDEX and the coordinates you'll be able to "navigate" through rows and columns. I suggest you mark this question as answered and post a new one if you struggle in researching that with your example, your findings and what you'd need 

Comment: Thank you, but can you convert this as you converted my question formula? I will adjust other formulas accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Unclear of the full scope but from your expected result scenario(in Column F) you seem to be pulling off second match(if any). well in that case try:

```
=BYROW(D:D,LAMBDA(dx,IF(dx="",,IFNA(FILTER(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(B:B,A:A=dx),2,1),{0;1})))))
```

- 

[image]