# Apply complex formula to whole column using MAP or ARRAY FORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This is a followup to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225617/array-formula-is-not-working-with-the-combination-of-vlookup-and-indirect-match/75226119?noredirect=1#comment132750333_75226119).

[@Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20363318/mart%C3%ADn) and [@rockinfreakshow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479575/rockinfreakshow) helped me to convert the following formula using `MAP` and `BYROW` respectively.

**Formula before conversion in F1 cell:**

```
=if(Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(E1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=E1,"",Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(E1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))
```

**Formula solution in F1 cell:**

```
=MAP(D:D,E:E,LAMBDA(d,e,IFERROR(IF(d="","",INDEX(FILTER(B:B,A:A=d,ROW(B:B)>MATCH(e,B:B,0)),1)))))
```

As I was expecting that the solution would be `ARRAYFORMULA` wrapping and I would convert the next formula by myself but that was not the case. So I am looking for your help to convert these:

**Formula in G1 cell:**

```
=if(or(Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(F1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=E1,Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(F1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=F1)
,"",Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(F1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))
```

and

**Formula in H1 cell:**

```
=if(or(Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=E1,Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=F1,Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),"")=G1)
,"",Iferror(vlookup($D1, INDIRECT("$"&"A"&MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0)+1&":$B"),2,false),""))
```

Now, my expectation is if we are able to find the solution for G1, H1 formulas, I should be able to replicate it for formulas in other cells `I1,J1,K1..`

I have linked a sheet for your testing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13XLZvvdzK_mqr4Ous50cIEfernw2XrPJWvVgt1hFxtk/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello again! Had to leave earlier. What's your expected result? A horizontal list of matches from each person? The previously given MAP won't be useful this time. You can't make an array formula that refers to cells inside itself. If you explain your desired result or logic, we'll be able to provide you a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very heavy spreadsheet! You may try deleting all your data in E:AU and use this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR (SPLIT(BYROW(D1:INDEX(D1:D,COUNTA(D1:D)),LAMBDA(v,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B:B,A:A=v)))),",")))`

It joins the filtered values per row, and then splits them in your desired columns

Comment: Was looking into it again. If your final goal is to reach the result in AV, you can dismiss all E:AT and use: `=BYROW(D1:INDEX(D1:D,COUNTA(D1:D)),LAMBDA(v, CONCATENATE (FILTER(B:B,A:A=v))))`

Comment: ok, some values of this formula do not align with the previous formulas values. For example in row1, old formulas generate values until Column N, while our new formula generate values until Column Q, same happens in row 47,49,51. That would make difference in result in Column AV

Comment: That's because there are repeated values in column F assigned to different values in column A. Then with MATCH as you used, there would be fake matches and probably skipped values in some rows. Obviously column AV will have different outcomes. Just saying that if you're final goal is that and aligns to your expectations, you can delete all those E:AT columns and solve everything in a single formula and single column

Comment: so you are saying, this formula is generating values with more accuracy than the previous formulas?

Comment: Exactly, in row 1 you were missing 3 values because of the mismatch

Comment: thanks once again, I request you to please explain a bit the working of this formula in your answer `(why the result is more accurate than the previous formulas, issue with the previous formulas and how does it work)`. As a beginner, It would help me to learn about it and anyone out there looking to acheive the same.

Comment: Basically I'm checking at every row and filtering B values according to A values. BYROW lets me repeat a process "row by row" . The expression `D1:INDEX(D1:D,COUNTA(D1:D))` can actually be replaced to a closed value, something like D1:D1100 or something like that. What I was trying to avoid is to repeat the process the 8k rows you had in that sheet. Returning to the formula, at every row with FILTER "collects" every value from B that matches in A. With Textjoin I put them all together in an unique cell per row (which BYROW needs), but then with ARRAYFORMULA and SPLIT you're able to separate

Comment: I hope it's more or less clear, you can go to the documentation of BYROW, FILTER, TEXTJOIN and SPLIT. The important thing is why I chose them. In the case of your previous formula, it was a nice one indeed. You handled to find a value, and with MATCH and INDIRECT narrow the lookup to the next rows. BUT you had repeated values non-corresponding with different values of A. Then when using MATCH you weren't able to see if the narrowed row was from a correct value of A or not, leading to mismatches and "jumping" values unintentionally. If there were no duplicates, it would have worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly the formula does but try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(res,if(res=E1:E11,,res))(XLOOKUP(D1:D11,A1:A11,B1:B11,,,-1)))
```

Comment: in which cell should I put this: G1? H1?

Comment: if I understood what you're trying to do. The formula is replicating the behavior of column F.

Comment: yes, but G1, H1, and so on contain if(or) and increasing indirect, Match conditions.

Comment: if you explain in words what is the desired output I will take another look.

Comment: that still doesn't explain *in words* what is the desired result. What are those formulas doing exactly?